# Some missing channel entries in relationship fieldtype

Tags: channel-entries, relationships

I have added a multiple relationship field to a channel, however a few entries in the selected channels are not appearing in the relationship selection list, yet the entry is open and can be viewed in both the control panel and frontend. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Fields [Add/Edit](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/custom_fields_edit.html), check your Relationship Field Options and compare against the entries you are expecting to appear.

- Include in Selection

  - Expired Entries?
  - Future Entries?
- Limit entries by category
- Authors
- Limit entries by status
- Limit entries to X returned